# How to proactively deal with business plan that seems to phase out my position?

Tags: planning

I work at a small marketing/web design company. While I do write some basic web code, here my job is simply to do web and graphic design. Currently I work about 25-30 hours a week, part time.

At a business meeting we had, my boss discussed that we'd stop going after multiple smaller clients and instead go for larger projects. I already don't have full time work, so I'm thinking this will bring me even less graphic work since we're essentially chasing fewer projects.

In this case, I don't feel that there's much I can study on my own to make myself more useful. This is because they already have a front end developer who does what I can do, and its unrealistic for me to get into heavy server side stuff in this shorter time frame (though I'll be returning back to school to finish my degree next year).

I am afraid the business is phasing out my work and position.  How can I best proactively deal with this situation?

Comment: Why are you assuming that you won't be needed? Big websites and clients need graphic design, too

Comment: Larger projects surely need more graphics per project.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem, even with smci's edit.  The evidence you present does not indicate that your workplace is phasing you out, so strategies to deal with that are of little value to present.

Comment: @gnasher729, HorusKol - for what it's worth, from my experience bigger projects require proportionally less design and more codding.

Comment: Why are you asking us? What did your boss say when you asked him?

Answer (score 46):

> my boss discussed that we'd stop going after multiple smaller clients and instead go for larger projects.

My assumption is that your company is changing their approach in order to grow. As companies grow, they take on more work, and need to hire additional people.

> I'm thinking this will bring me even less graphic work since we're essentially chasing less projects.

Larger projects can often mean **more** work -- if the scope of work is increased, and the client desires quick delivery, it's common to have 2-3 people performing the same role.

> I don't feel that there's much I can study on my own to make myself more useful.

Continuous learning is a requirement in today's workplace. Find something you are interested in that may be related to your job (such as UX, or user experience), or discover new and different ways to do what you already do, but better and more efficiently.

Learning more coding can't hurt, but in my experience, people who do graphic design are always in demand because it's something very hard to do well. And front-end developer rarely equals designer.

**Have a conversation with your boss** -- ask what you can do to make this transition successful, and find out where you fit into the overall plan.

You may need to start looking around for other opportunities, but this change in company strategy does not necessarily mean the end of your contributions there.

Comment: You make a **very** good point that a business is unlikely to (deliberately) follow a strategy of "getting less work"!

Answer (score 6):

> In this case, I don't feel that there's much I can study on my own to
>   make myself more useful. This is because they already have a front end
>   developer who does what I can do, and its unrealistic for me to get
>   into heavy server side stuff in this shorter time frame (though I'll
>   be returning back to school to finish my degree next year).
>
> How should I deal with a situation in which, moving forward, the
>   business is phasing out my work and position?

If you are correct that you can't make yourself more useful with study, that you can't do heavy server side stuff, and that the plan is phasing out your position, then there are only two options

- Hope that the business plan takes long enough so that you are back in school before you are no longer needed
- Find a new job

It it were me, I'd be hoping for the first option, while actively working on the second.

Comment: There is also #3: Get more competent. The statement that one can not make oneself more useful through self study in this field is basically a fast way OUT of the field.

Comment: I know. But it means the OP better gets a job he is qualified for because anything in or close to IT is constant learning or self stufy. This attitude of him may well be the reason he may be out of the door one day - not the business plan.